# SQLite database with C# Unable to compare datetime datatype

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, datetime

I am using C# (.NET) and SQLite database with it.
I have a table in an SQLite database with a column called "InvoiceDate". I have chosen the datatype (in the db table) for the same as TEXT as I need it to be a datetime variable.

I am using the `System.Data.SQLite reference`.

The following is my command text where I am facing the problem:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM InvoiceMaster WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '" 
                     + date1.ToString() + "' AND '" 
                     + date2.ToString() + "' ORDER BY InvoiceNumber";
```

I need to find all results where the column InvoiceDate falls between the given dates date1 and date2. But the problem is that I am getting the results even though I choose other dates for example I get the same results for the same month and dates even though I choose a different year. There is something wrong with the command text and I also need to know what type of datatype should I choose in the db table. Please do let me know how I should be writing the select command.

Comment: **[Possible SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)** Use prepared statement/parameter binding and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample code...

Comment: Did you do basic reasearch first? You have example in provided link

Comment: just trying to find it in google.....

Comment: You need to format the date strings correctly...

Answer (score 1):

From [1.2 Date and Time Datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> `TEXT` as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS")

Since `ToString()` does not generate this kind of format, you can use custom formatting like;

```
date1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
date2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

I'm not %100 about format but you might wanna use [The `"o"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Roundtrip) which represents;

> .. a custom date and time format string using a pattern that preserves
>   time zone information and emits a result string that complies with ISO
>   8601.

```
command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM InvoiceMaster 
                        WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2 
                        ORDER BY InvoiceNumber";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", date1.ToString("o"));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", date1.ToString("o));
```

Comment: That interesting because [ISO 8601](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977(v=sql.90).aspx) has format  **`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss[.mmm]`**. SQLite doc indicates that `T` is not part of this standard.

Comment: **ISO 8601** is culture independent. But not in format presented in SQLite doc. Please check **[demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/446263)** and correct one **[demo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/446265)**

Comment: @lad2025 You have a point but I wrote this format because the doc say so. I never used Sqlite honestly that's why I'm not %100 sure.

Comment: Tried the following:   command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM InvoiceMaster WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN 'DATETIME(" + date1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ")' AND 'DATETIME(" + date2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ")'";   STILL DOESN'T WORK

Comment: @SlickGuy I updated my answer. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method to convert your datetime

```
 private string DateTimeSQLite(DateTime datetime)
  {
    string dateTimeFormat = "{0}-{1}-{2} {3}:{4}:{5}.{6}";
    return string.Format(dateTimeFormat, datetime.Year,   
                         datetime.Month,datetime.Day, 
                         datetime.Hour, datetime.Minute,  
                          datetime.Second,datetime.Millisecond);
  }
```

or better make it a extension method.

```
 private static string DateTimeSQLite(this DateTime datetime)
 {}
```

Also use parametrized queries to avoid sql injection

```
string commandText = "SELECT * FROM InvoiceMaster 
                  WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN @date1 and @date2
                  ORDER BY InvoiceNumber"
yourcommand.Parameters.Add("@date1",date1.DateTimeSQLite());
yourcommand.Parameters.Add("@date2",date1.DateTimeSQLite());
```

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea because single digit month, day, hour, minute and seconds part will _not_ have leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have chosen to store the dates as `TEXT` field in the database, they must be formatted using ISO8601. Example:

```
2016-02-03T20:34:22Z
```

So once you have ensured that they are stored this way all that's left is parametrize your query:

```
DateTime date1 = ... get from somewhere
DateTime date2 = ... get from somewhere

using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=mydb.db;Version=3;"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM InvoiceMaster WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", date1.ToString("o"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", date2.ToString("o"));
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // do something with the results here
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I am using the `.ToString("o")` format specifier to ensure that the dates will be passed correctly to the database.